enormous delay to show the desktop after installing ubuntu 24,4.1
After installing Ubuntu 24.4.1, I need to spend 4 minutes or more after typing my password. The screen turns to black and, after 4 minutes, asks for the password again. Four minutes more and then I can work. How can I resolve this?
